# React - Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I'm new to react.

My error is:

> Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element

I've Googled this plenty of times and find people who have this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Mine doesn't contain:

> _registerComponent(...):

Here are my files:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: './index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: './bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
    }
};
```

The most common issue I found people were having with this error is that they put `<script>` in the head or before the `<div>`. Yet I don't do neither of these so I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Instead of putting it inside the body tag, can you try to put outside the body before closing the html tag like this </body> <script src="./bundle.js"></script></html>.As the dom are rendered after loading all the elements.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal it still throws the same error.

Comment: It works fine for me after I've added a .babelrc

Comment: @Axnyff my .babelrc has: `{
    "presets":[
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ]
}` Is this correct?

Comment: I created the same thing and it works fine for me. It looks like react can't find a dom element with an id of root, can you console.log the result of     document.getElementById('root') ?

Comment: @Axnyff I added a console.log after the ReactDOM.render and it shows nothing. This will be an extremely nooby question, but is this where I should be adding it?

Comment: Add it just before, if you've already got the exception from react, your code will not run further and the console.log won't be executed

Comment: @Axnyff it shows null.

Comment: It means the element with a root id doesn't exist. Are you sure your html contains it? If you check the html in your navigator, do you see that element?

Comment: @Axnyff it is there exactly as it should be. This is why I'm flabbergasted by this issue I'm having.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158437/discussion-between-axnyff-and-edward).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Axnyff for his help as it resolved my question. The problem was with a dependency I was using, webpack-dev-middleware.

Answer (score 3):

I'm definitely a little late to the party here, but would like to post an answer for those who want to use `webpack-dev-middleware` instead of circumventing it.

The problem, for me, was that basic setup for `webpack-dev-middleware` is shown in the webpack docs using `html-webpack-plugin` with a default configuration. This plugin dynamically generates a new `index.html` file along with your `bundle.js` on save, so even though I wrote an `index.html` file that contained `<div id="root"></div>`, that wasn't the one that was being served to the browser. I was able to verify this by running `/node_modules/.bin/webpack` and watching the output in my public path directory.

My solution is as follows:

Add a configuration object to the declaration of the WebpackHtmlPlugin:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "boilerplate",
      template: path.join(__dirname, "pathto", "template.html"),
      inject: "body",
    }),
  ],
```

(This sets the title of the template file, its location, and directs `html-webpack-plugin`to push all script tags into the bottom of the body element of the generated file.) The template is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

More info can be found here:

- https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/
- https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options